# Is it possible to add a identity to a GROUP BY using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, row-number

Is it possible to add a identity column to a GROUP BY so that each duplicate has a identity number?

My original data looks like this:

```
1    AAA  [timestamp]
2    AAA  [timestamp]
3    BBB  [timestamp]
4    CCC  [timestamp]
5    CCC  [timestamp]
6    CCC  [timestamp]
7    DDD  [timestamp]
8    DDD  [timestamp]
9    EEE  [timestamp]
....
```

And I want to convert it to:

```
1    AAA   1
2    AAA   2
4    CCC   1
5    CCC   2
6    CCC   3
7    DDD   1
8    DDD   2
...
```

The solution was:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[RankIt]
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT  *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY col2 ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS ranking 
FROM MYTABLE;

END
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try using [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) if you are using Sql Server 2005

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Val VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1,'AAA'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2,'AAA'
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 3,'BBB' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 4,'CCC' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 5,'CCC' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 6,'CCC' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 7,'DDD' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 8,'DDD' 
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 9,'EEE' 

SELECT  *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY VAL ORDER BY Val)
FROM    @Table
```

Comment: i tried SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY col2) AS ranking  FROM table   and it crashes my SQL2005 management studio...

Comment: Remember to use **PARTITION BY** as in the example.

Comment: SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY col2)  also crashes my sql managment studio.   this rank and partition stuff is wierd....  i cant figure it out.

Comment: What do you mean by **CRASH** ? Like fatal error, restart the app?

Comment: got it working with difficulty.  thanks very much astander... you got me looking in the right place.  i'll update my question with the answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
create table #testalot
(
  [id] int identity,
  data varchar(50)
)

insert #testalot (data) values('AAA')
insert #testalot (data) values('AAA')
insert #testalot (data) values('BBB')
insert #testalot (data) values('CCC')
insert #testalot (data) values('CCC')
insert #testalot (data) values('CCC')
insert #testalot (data) values('DDD')
insert #testalot (data) values('DDD')

select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY data ORDER BY data DESC) AS 'Number'
 from #testalot

 drop table #testalot
```

returns

```
id  data Number
1   AAA  1
2   AAA  2
3   BBB  1
4   CCC  1
5   CCC  2
6   CCC  3
7   DDD  1
8   DDD  2
```

Comment: sigh... click the save and the page comes up with someone else entering the same answer 3 mins earlier.

Comment: i never could get it to work with ROW_NUMBER().  i ended up using RANK() .

Comment: -shrug- I tested the code above.  They actually give different results when you have ties.