# How to increment an integer based on a group in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Here's my query:

```
IF Object_id('tempdb..##delist') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE ##delist
SELECT jl.jobid as 'JobID',
       jl.CustomObjectName as 'DEName',
       cols.name as 'ColumnName',
       null as 'ColumnNumber'
INTO   ##delist
FROM   ##joblist AS jl WITH (nolock)
       JOIN sys.tables tbls with (nolock) on tbls.name = jl.CustomObjectName
       JOIN sys.columns cols with (nolock) on cols.object_id = tbls.object_id
WHERE cols.name <> '_CustomObjectKey'
```

Here's my result set:

[image]

What I'm ultimately looking for is a way to number the ColumnNumber data fields incrementally BY "DEName".  So in other words, for every ColumnName for each DEName, I want the ColumnNumber to start at 1, and go to however many unique ColumnNames there are for each DEName.  Any ideas?

Comment: could you post expected numbering as well?

Comment: Sight detour...https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ That nolock hint is far more sinister than most people realize.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to return a incremental group number per group in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14359749/how-to-return-a-incremental-group-number-per-group-in-sql)

Comment: Sorry, on further inspection, I flagged a poor duplicate.. this is a better duplicate:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066178/is-it-possible-to-add-a-identity-to-a-group-by-using-sql

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select . . .,
       row_number() over (partition by jl.CustomObjectName order by (select NULL)) as columnNumber
```

Comment: OP _may_ also want to add `jl.jobid` to the `PARTITION BY` if there is a possibility that a `jl.CustomObjectName` can appear in multiple `jl.jobid`s.

Comment: @Shawn . . . That is a good point.  At some point we do need to trust what an OP says, though:  "What I'm ultimately looking for is a way to number the ColumnNumber data fields incrementally BY "DEName". "

Comment: True. I was more commenting for future readers and to point out to the OP that they may not have realized that the numbering could change if `jobID` ended up being a primary partition column. :-)